# Getting data from one class to make it the title of stackNavigator tab?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, navigationbar, stack-navigator

```
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Navigator extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const TitleNameParam = navigation.getParam('TitleNameParam');
    var TitleNameString = JSON.stringify(TitleNameParam);
    var TitleNameObject = JSON.parse(TitleNameString);
  }


}


const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Launching: {
    screen: LaunchingScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "Launching Soon",
      headerTitleAllowFontScaling: true,
      headerBackTitle: "Back"
    }
  },

  InfoScreen: {
    screen: InfoScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: Navigator.TitleNameParam,
    }
  }
});



export default AppNavigator;
```

So what I want to do is get data (that's from an API) from one class to the stack navigator class so I can replace the title to whatever the data is. What I have right now is class Navigator getting data ( from TitleNameParam ) that makes the data into a string in which the navigator attempts to get it in the InfoScreen tab, but nothing shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use navigationOptions on the InfoScreen component:

```
class InfoScreen extends React.Component {
  // Set the navigation options for `react-navigation`
  static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
    return {
      headerTitle: navigation.getParam('TitleNameParam');
    }
  }
…
}
```

When you navigate to this route use:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('InfoScreen', {TitleNameParam: yourComputedTitleName})
```

Please let me know if this is correct.

Comment: YEP that's exactly what I did, figured it out a couple hours after posting my problem, thanks!